# Mongodb Increment value inside nested array

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I´m using mongotemplate for Spring, and I was wondering how I could increment a value of one of my documents that I have in an array atomically. Imagine that we have

```
{'a':1,
   b:[{_id:341432,
       c:2
      },
      {_id:341445,
       c:3
      }]};
```

What I would like is increment c from 3 to 4 for the _id 341445

I have been using findAndModify but I dont know how can I make it for a nested document in an array.

Regards.

Comment: So far the only thing that I found is determinate the index of the array like b.0.c=11111 any better idea?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

To update an element in an array field, you can use the [positional $ operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/positional/)

For example, the following js increments c from 3 to 4 for _id 341445:

```
db.collection.update({a:1, "b._id":341445} , {$inc:{"b.$.c":1}})
```

Comment: Thanks!, but remember that your answer have to be extrapolated to Java

Comment: This will not work when the update query is used with upsert.

Comment: Thank You Thank You Thank You. I've been spending three+ hours trying to get this to work!!! Great answer!!

Comment: @Lind Qin, thanks it works. Here spring data solution for the ones who might be interested: `mongoOperations.updateFirst(new Query(Criteria.where("a").is(1).and("b._id").is(341445)),new Update().inc("b.$.c", 1), YourClass.class);`