# How can I increment an array element referenced by index in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

Let's say we have a collection with documents like this:

```
{
 _id : "some id",
 items: [
  {item: "item A", count: 5},
  {item: "item B", count: 3},
  {item: "item C", count: 9}
]
}
```

How can I increment the value by 1 of the third (or any other index value) element in items array?

And I want to reference not by matching value like in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16037788/mongodb-increment-value-inside-nested-array), but by index.

Comment: Why did you ask the question if you already knew the answer? Also possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16037788/mongodb-increment-value-inside-nested-array

Comment: @SarathNair it is completely okay. albeit it is a duplicate. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290038/answer-your-own-question-qa-style

Comment: @Idos "So I came up with a question, did my research, and found no help on S.O" the question has already been anwered here in SO

Comment: I have seen the question mentioned and I think there is enough difference to add as separate. In my case it is referenced by index, not by matching value.

Answer (score 6):

In the mongo shell it can be done this way:

```
db.my_collection.update(
 {_id: "some id"},
 {$inc: {"items.2.count": 1}}
)
```

Using PyMongo it can be done this way:

```
db.my_collection.update_one({"_id": "some id"},
                            {"$inc": {"items." + str(2) + ".count": 1}})
```

Comment: What if the array does not actually exist? Instead of creating `[1]`, it creates `{"0": 1}`. How can I ask it to use integer keys there?