# How to create new object for a new date in mongodb?

Tags: database, mongodb, web-applications, relational-database, non-relational-database

I want to change the value of a variable named *count* in mongodb. Count is needed for every day.

For example, if count changes from 15 to 17 in one day, i want to update the existing object. Again start the next day with 0 and keep track of it.

This way I will have 365 objects(in a year) for a user which has the count value for each day.

How to do it in mongodb? or is relational db more suitable for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an array of objects (counters) in the document and save the counter in a specific object.
[image]

Comment: How to detect the change in date?. I mean how to differenciate day 1 and day 2?

Comment: If the entry is from same date I want to update the existing value, if it is a different day, I want to store it as the count of new date. Count will vary in the same day as per the user increases the count

Comment: To update or create use db.collection.findAndModify()
For find document use $elemMatch

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16037788/mongodb-increment-value-inside-nested-array

Comment: Can I store values with timestamp inside the object array? like 2021.07.01 --> count = 15, 2021.07.02 --> count = 06

Comment: Yes, you can store